# gatttool can't connect to a bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, gatttool

I'm trying to connect a bluetooth module to a Raspberry Pi3 using gatttool.
First, I launched gatttool with following command, and tried to connect;

```
$ sudo gatttool -b (MAC ADDRESS) -I
```

Then an error message was shown.

```
Error: connect: Device or resource busy (16)
```

I searched it and found some solutions. After that, I tried again.

```
$ sudo gatttool -t random -b (MAC ADDRESS) -I
```

Then it attempted to connect to the bluetooth module for a while, and showed following error.

```
Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

I never heard about a situation that somebody encountered both of these errors. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Have you ever managed to find a solution to this? I currently struggle with the same problem.